# How do I mask make sure users are typing numbers only and mask them as they type with a timeout?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I'm setting up credit card payment and I want the input text be masked with # when typing, with a timeout of like half a second. also, nothing should be displayed if the user isn't typing a number.

```
if(fields.value === NaN){
      e.preventDefault;
}
```

it still types alphabet

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` maybe?

Comment: if(isNaN(fields.value)){...} [NaN equals to nothing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#Testing_against_NaN)

Comment: `NaN === NaN = false`

Comment: const smartInput = (event, fieldIndex) => {
  if(isNaN(event.key)){
   event.preventDefault();
  }
 }

Comment: working, now... but how do I mask it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok at first the problem you already solved with `e.preventDefault()`

So there is the else case left. Lets do it like when you enter a password on mobile.

At first we save the the old value and the new character to a data attribute for later.

Then we hide all previously entered characters. If we have hidden all previously entered characters we can add a `setTimeout` which hides the last character after 0.5 seconds. And we need to clear the timeout so it always takes 0.5 seconds to mask the input

```js
let timeout;

$("#cc").keypress(e => {
  const currentVal = parseInt(e.key);
  const input = $("#cc");
  if(isNaN(currentVal)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    input.attr("data-value", input.attr("data-value") + e.key);
    input.val(new Array(input.val().length + 1).join("#"));
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {      
      input.val(input.val().substr(0, input.val().length - 1) + "#");
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cc" type="text" data-value=""/>
```